# How to know when column is created in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is there any way to know when a column is created in mysql from the metadata?

Comment: What metadata are you talking about? `SHOW CREATE TABLE`?

Comment: Why do you want to know that?

Comment: Or `SHOW FIELDS` as well. This question is pretty open-ended.

Comment: any metadata, if I run an alter table and add a col, when did I add that col?

Comment: btw none of the ones above show the date created for each col

Comment: Oh, you mean *when* in time the column was created, where I read that as when meaning *if* the column had been created or not in the present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Not unless you leave comments on the column yourself.  Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/columns-table.html